# Custom routing in Symfony2 - /bundle/controller/action/params

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a question:
Is it possible to create a routing rule in Symfony2 that picks the /bundle/controller/action/params from the URL?

The "abstract" routing.yml in my mind could look like that:

```
Directory{nameofbundle}Bundle:
    pattern:  /{nameofbundle}/{controller}/{action}/{params}
    defaults: { _controller: Directory{nameofbundle}Bundle:{controller}:{action}}
```

So if I'd go to the url www.myweb.com/Xyz/Asd/ffs/
it would launch: an action named *ffsAction* from *AsdController* from a bundle *src/Asd/XyzBundle/*

Is this possible or do I have to create a rule for every bundle, every controller and every action in it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern

```
default:
    pattern:  /{_controller}
```

Then you are allowed to call you controller action directly from url like this

```
http://mysite.com/MyBundle:DefaultController:index
```

Comment: Is it a good practice? I believe it's against the MVC pattern rule, that view should know nothing about the logic (model and controller).

Comment: You are right @thorinkor, but it's simple way to test quickly what you are doing